# common crypto and bouncy castle, PBKDF2 generation

Tags: android, ios

I am working on an iOS app and android app, for iOS I am using common crypto, and for android bouncy castle. 
I noticed that in android when I generate PBKDF2, if I use a salt or pass 00000000000000000000000000000000 (  32 hex digits ZERO which correspond to 16 bytes set to ZERO ) the password comes out the same.

I was playing with common crypto PBKDF2, basically this call

```
 CCKeyDerivationPBKDF
```

and under the same conditions, I generate a PBKDF2 without SALT, but when I pass 00000000000000000000000000000000 as salt for the same parameters, I get a different PBKDF2.

Is that normal? should I expect the same behavior from bouncy castle and common crypto?
should this be a concern?

Comment: Do they generate correct results for the [test vectors at my Github repository](https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords/PBKDF2-Test-Vectors) - the default PBKDF2 will be PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1.  It's in OpenDocument/LibreOffice format, so you can use =CONCATENATE to generate an automated test suite for your application.